# vmcloak failed after installation, invalid syntax

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine, cuckoo

I've been having some issues with vmcloak after installation. I successfully installed vmcloak v.0.4.1 and when I try and run it I get this error:

```
Successfully installed vmcloak-0.4.1
(cuckoo) cuckoo@nick-VirtualBox:~/cuckoo$ vmcloak
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cuckoo/cuckoo/bin/vmcloak", line 5, in <module>
    from vmcloak.main import main
  File "/home/cuckoo/cuckoo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vmcloak/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import agent, main, vm, misc
  File "/home/cuckoo/cuckoo/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vmcloak/agent.py", line 43
    def execute(self, command, async=False):
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was wondering if anyone had run into this issue before, and if so how I might go about fixing it.

Comment: I have this exact same issue. You ever find a solution?

Comment: @JoshBarrere It's a problem with permissions. Run the entire installation process with root and do the cuckoo user creation afterwards when everything is set up. Takes some tweaking but that's what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not answer but have the same error but for different description but don't wanna duplicate the question.

```
$ sudo vmcloak init --verbose --win7x64 win7x64base --ramsize 2048
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/vmcloak", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('VMCloak==1.0', 'console_scripts', 'vmcloak')()
  File "/home/cuckoo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 489, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/cuckoo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2852, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/cuckoo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2443, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/cuckoo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2449, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMCloak-1.0-py2.7.egg/vmcloak/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import agent, main, misc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/VMCloak-1.0-py2.7.egg/vmcloak/agent.py", line 97
    cmd = f"taskkill /IM {process_name}"
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Kindly if anyone find a solution to share it?